# How to get all of the Facebook Graph API page feed?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.3, facepy

Using Python:

```
from facepy import GraphAPI  
key = 'My Access_Token'
a = GraphAPI(key)
response = a.get('Page_ID/posts')
print response
```

If I run this code, It shows me data in JSON format! And Limited Data. I want to get Years of feeds from my page.

In response I get Next tag URL: If I put this URL in Browser I can access more data. In one request we can fetch 200 feeds at a time.

How can I get data in bulk? I want to collect data of 5 years from public page!

Comment: The API has limits and default values - you'll want to look at the API documentation to change the format, if possible, and the number of results.

Comment: pleaase give me some hint to get bulk data!!!

Answer (score 3):

Facebook's GraphAPI uses paging for API responses:
If you query `v2.5/{page-id}/posts` then the result will provide you with a data array and beneath this there is the paging section. You get the "previous" and "next" query string you just have to call again and again. API won't allow you more than 100 results per "page".

Comment: @ShivShankar You are welcome. If my answer resolved your problem I would appreciate if you mark it answer to the question, so that others with the same problem will find it.